# When did James Cook's wife learn about his death?

Tags: age-of-discovery

[James Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Cook) died on 14 February 1779 in Kealakekua Bay, Hawaii. When did his wife Elizabeth hear about his death?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question, but please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help] center, and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Answer (score 11):

According to *Captain Cook: The Life, Death and Legacy of History's Greatest Explorer*, by Vanessa Collingridge -

> ON 11 JANUARY 1780, an announcement appeared in the London Gazette:
>
> > Captain Clerke of His Majesty’s Sloop Resolution, in a letter to Mr Stephens, dated 8th of June 1779, in the Harbour of St Peter and St Paul, Kampschatka, which was received yesterday, gives the melancholy account of the celebrated Captain Cook, late commander of that Sloop, with four of his private Marines having been killed on 14th of February last at the island of O’Why’he, one of a group of new discovered Islands in the 22nd Degree of North Latitude, in an affray with a numerous and tumultuous Body of Natives.
>
> *Captain Cook*. Ebury Publishing (2011).

Collingridge goes on to note -

> There is no record of how Elizabeth heard of her husband’s death, though one presumes a messenger was sent from the Admiralty. After all she had endured, it is hard not to hope that Stephens, Palliser or Sandwich might have gone to Mile End personally to help break the devastating news.

Where *Stephens* refers to [Sir Philip Stephens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Philip_Stephens,_1st_Baronet), Secretary to the Admiralty (to whom all ships correspondence was addressed), *Palliser* was [Admiral Sir Hugh Palliser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugh_Palliser) and *Sandwich* was [John Montagu, 4th Earl of Sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Montagu,_4th_Earl_of_Sandwich) who was First Lord of the Admiralty. All three were closely involved with Cook's career.